# Bash: Script output to terminal session stops but script finishes normal

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm opening an ssh-session to a remote server and execute a larger (around 1000 lines) bash-script on the remote machine. It involves several very CPU-intensive calls which run for up to three minutes each. To track the scripts progress it echoes messages placed at several points in the script.

In general the script runs smoothly. From time to time the script runs trough (the resulting file on the remote machine is correct) but the output to the terminal stops. Ctrl-C doesn't help, no prompt, just a frozen session. top in a separate session shows normal execution of the script.

My question: How keep the session alive?

local machine:

```
$ sw_vers  
ProductName:    Mac OS X  
ProductVersion: 10.9  
BuildVersion:   13A603
```

remote machine:

```
$ lsb_release -d  
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
```

Comment: Could you post the script?

Comment: @Dan: I'd prefer not to as there is quite a bit hardcoded information in it. It is nothing crazy, just a lot of curl, while-loops and an unhealthy dose of `gmt`* calls.  *`GMT - The Generic Mapping Tools, Version 5.1.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would recommend using `screen` or `tmux` on the remote terminal for exactly this reason.

Those apps will allow the remote process to continue even if your local SSH session times out.

- http://www.bangmoney.org/presentations/screen.html
- http://tmux.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If it is really just a timeout – shouldn't I get something like     Write failed: Broken pipe
    $

Comment: not necessarily if the remote session hangs (as you seem to suggest).  I've had the same problem.  Screen or Tmux allows you to reconnect to the remote session in-process.  I believe screen is preinstalled on most linux distros (and OSX)

Comment: Well, with `screen` it runs (for now) as advertised. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Start a screen on the remote machine and run your command from it:

```
screen -S largeScript
```

And then

```
./yourLargeScript.sh
```

Whenever your `ssh` session gets frozen, you can kill it with `~.`

If you `ssh` again, you can grab back your screen by:

```
screen -dr largeScript
```

Comment: Thank you for expanding Donovans suggestion with actual calls.

Answer (score 1):

Make it log to a file instead (perhaps via `syslog`), and `tail` that file from wherever is convenient for you. This also helps detach the script so you can run it headless, from a cron job, etc. Also, if the log file has read access for others, they too can monitor it.